# SignalR client server connected but not pushing data to client on production server

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have developed a web app using SignalR and its working perfectly on my development server. But for some unknown reasons its not working on production server.

I have done some tests:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        console.log('started');

});
```

This always gives my 'started' in console as expected. So client and server are connected. But when I send any data like login credentials, i am not receiving anything back.

Here is the connection frames image. As you can see client is sending data to server but not receiving anything in response.

[image]

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{

        Clients.All.Listen("Connected to HUB");

}
```

CLIENT SIDE Listen method:

```
hub.client.listen = function (response) {

    console.log('Listen', response);

}
```

There is a Listen method which I use to debug. This doesn't print anything. So signalr client server are not connecting.

EDIT:

Reported issue here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4279 if this helps.

EDIT2:

My webapp is a Vue js 2 app. I compiled using vue-cli and uploaded to server. My signalr.js file is copied from an ASP.NET MVC project.

I made a Test ASP.NET MVC 5 app with SignalR 2.4 and I was able to communicate on live server.

Comment: Can you share minimal visual studio solution to reproduce the issue? IT is working fine for me with SignalR 2.0

Comment: Please mention your production server, is it IIS or Azure App Service or Azure SignalR Services?

Comment: @AzazulHaq none

Comment: Then what should I assume about the server mentioned in question. "its not working on production server"

Comment: @AzazulHaq oh sorry, Its IIS server.

Comment: Please mention IIS server version. Also I'm the login endpoint is working fine on your development environment.

Comment: @AzazulHaq no nothing is working. No event is being fired from server side. For example in onConnect I have Clients.All.Listen("Connected to HUB"); but this method doesn't get fired and I don't see any output in console. Whereas this works ok on my local server

Comment: Can you please write the code of how you handle listen method on client side?

Comment: Updated my question, I have mentioned that my app (client) is Vue 2 app compiled using vue-cli 3

Comment: 2 things to consider: Is there a chance your minification is renaming the listen callback in your production server? Does your production server have WebSockets enabled?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting

**IIS issues**

This section contains issues with Internet Information Services.

SignalR works on Visual Studio development server, but not in IIS

> SignalR is supported on IIS 7.0 and 7.5, but support for extensionless URLs must be added. To add support for extensionless
>   URLs, see https://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368
>
> SignalR requires ASP.NET to be installed on the server (ASP.NET is not installed on IIS by default). To install ASP.NET, see ASP.NET
>   Downloads.